# Change the NavigationDrawer selectedItem from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an application with one Activity (ActivityMain) and some fragments. A NavigationDrawer controls the switch of the fragments. In some fragments the user has the opportunity to switch to another fragment without opening the NavigationDrawer (for example with a button click).

Everything works well, if I use the NavigationDrawer to switch between fragments, but if I use a control (eg. button) within a fragment to switch to another fragment, I cannot set the selectedItem property of the NavigationDraver's (actually a ListView in the ND) selectedItem property.

The NavigationDrawer's selectedItem property is stored with sharedPreferences, and restored in the onDrawerOpened method in the **NavigationDrawer fragment**.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}
```

I've tried to put the selection index within the onClick event of the View to STATE_SELECTED_POSITION value, as follows, but it doesn't worked. I've also cannot get the value from the sharedPreferences in the **other Fragment**.

```
   public void navigationRowClick(View view) {

       SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.tr_conv:
            sp.edit().putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 1);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeFrame(1);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).restoreActionBar();
            break;
        case R.id.trCalc:
            sp.edit().putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 2);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeFrame(2);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).restoreActionBar();
            break;
        case R.id.trCalo:
            Integer i = sp.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 100); // get value test
            String s = i.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
```

My question is, how should I set the selectedItem of the NavigationDrawer from another fragment? Do You have a best practice to this task?

Thanks is advance for the suggestions.

Comment: in the onClick event of the button that switches the fragments put outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, position); the position would be the one that the fragment has in the list in the ND

Comment: Thank You for the suggession, Goran. Unfortunately the suggested solution doesn't worked. Maybe I haven't used the SharedPreferences the right way. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the onClick event for the button that switches the fragment:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).changePosition(1);
        sp.edit().putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 1).**commit()**;
    }
});

//in MainActivity.java
private void changePosition(int position)
{
    list.setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

this works if you have set the android:choiceMode="singleChoice" attribute to the list.

Another way of doing things is to do it in the adapter of the listview:

```
.....
{
    private int mSelectedItem = 0;

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if(position == mSelectedItem) 
        {

        } 
        else 
        {

        }
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int position)
    {
        mSelectedItem = position;
    }
}


//in MainActivity.java
private void changePosition(int position)
{
    adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also make sure to commit the changes to the SharedPreferences:

```
sp.edit().putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 1).**commit()**;
```

maybe you are doing it in some other place, but I don't see it in the snippets you have shown.

Comment: Thank You @Goran. With your valuable suggessions i found the working solution. I needed to commit the changes to the SharedPreferences. In the onDrawerStateChanged method of the NavigationDrawer I read back the STATE_SELECTED_POSITION value, and  set checked the state of the related list item.